# Meteor mobile web app touch support

Tags: mobile, browser, meteor

I have a Meteor app that's having problems on mobile browsers. I'm using the autocomplete package (meteor-autocomplete), but I can't select the autocomplete options that drop down using touch. It works fine on the desktop browser when I click on the options. What's the problem? Also, how can I modify the app for mobile browsers (presentation, etc.).

Thanks

Edit:
Here's the html template code:

```
<template name="form">
{{> inputAutocomplete settings=settings id="food" class="form-control" name="food" placeholder="e.g. Chicken Pot Pie"}}
</template>
```

And here's Template.form.helpers:

```
Template.form.helpers({
  settings: function() {
    return {
      position: "bottom",
      limit: 5,
      rules: 
      [
      {
          collection: Records,
          field: 'food',
          matchAll: true,
          template: Template.foodFill
        }
        ] 
    };
  },
  records: function() {
    return Records.find().fetch();
  }
});
```

And the Records collection holds all the entries to be used by autocomplete.

Comment: please share the (minimal) code that would allows us to reproduce the error. Thanks.

Comment: I added the code to the post